# TWA custom activity/ animation on initial load (before launch url)

Tags: android-studio, animation, splash-screen, trusted-web-activity

I have created TWA using bubblewrap, and its working fine.
But I need to add animation to splash screen.
I tried following method:

- Using gif (not supported)
- Creating custom activity along with Launching activity and adding animation (not working properly)

I need to add zoom in effect to splash screen.
In native application, I am able to add required animation using custom activity activity.
but tried the same with twa and its not working as expected.

Please let me know if there is any other approach I can achieve animated splash screen with TWA.
I am stuck with this for last 2 days.